# Add the parameters of Docker run to docker-compose

Tags: linux, docker, selenium, docker-compose, yaml

I am running this command to start a selenium image and run my container:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 4445:4444 --shm-size 2g selenium/standalone-firefox:latest
```

I would like to integrate this command to my docker-compose file so I did the following which works:

```
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox:latest
    container_name: selenium
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
     - 4445:4444
```

But I  need to pass on as well the following parameter: `--shm-size 2g`
How can I do that in my `docker-compose.yml` file ?
Thanks!

Comment: Most `docker run` options have Compose file equivalents; see [Compose file version 3 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) and search that page for `shm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox:latest
    container_name: selenium
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
     - 4445:4444
    shm_size: '2gb'
```

Run the compose:

```
docker-compose up
```

Check it:

```
docker inspect <container-id> | grep ShmSize
            "ShmSize": 2147483648
```